# VSCode pdf-editor extension

Tags: visual-studio-code

I would like to develop an extension to VSCode that would auto-detect *.pdf files (By PDF filename extension or by reading magic bytes)

The extension will then know the PDF file format and will allow the opening the "binary" pdf file and allow for simple text editing

What is the way in vs code to "auto-detect" file by types?

And, Once detected what is the proper way to open a binary file for editing purposes?

Comment: I believe that [this](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/extension-guides/custom-editors) will answer you on the first question. The second one is harder I think and also depends on what do you mean by "editing"? Split / merge pages? Fill a form? Actual design it? Anyway, you can start with those projects (Just Googled it, never used them): https://github.com/TakeshiOkamoto/PDFDesigner, https://github.com/won21kr/pdfedit

Comment: Indeed this is the right direction.
Moreover, it actually contains solution to both challenges I presented. Indeed it's possible to create what they call a "custom editor". these editors come in two flavors: read only editors, which are pretty simple and editors that have the ability to edit the underlying resource (which are harder to implement but can manipulate the actual bytes on the filesystem). thanks @MoshFeu

Comment: Sure :) Good luck!  Notify me when the extension will be ready ;)